# Клонирование лицензионной Windows 7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, активация

Имею 10 идентичных машин с предустановленной лицензионной Windows 7 Starter. При первом запуске машины, получаю уже активированный Windows, т.е. лиц. ключ не надо вводить. Образ системы уже активированный лежит на жестком диске машины.

Задача, установить и настроить софт на одной машине, затем клонировать образ системы на другие 9 машин.

Вопрос, как произвести переактивацию Windows или сменить ключ в системе на склонированных машинах?

Comment: А машины требуют активацию после клонирования?

Comment: нет, они уже активированы

Comment: Для Windows не главное, чтобы ключ на машине совпадал с ключом на бумажке. Главное чтобы была бумажка. Для офиса и т.п. приложений - главное. Конечно, если у вас будет что-то весьма специфическое, тогда ладно, но в общем случае, и работы меньше, и WDS рабочий, и прицепиться не к чему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос решился. Чтобы удалить ключ из системы надо запустить командную строку(cmd.exe) от имени администратора и в ней пишите:

**slmgr.vbs /upk**

Эта команда удалит ключ из системы. Затем можно перезагрузить систему и пройти процедуру ввода ключа и активации. Но можно еще написать:

**slmgr.vbs /ipk [ваш лицензионный ключ]** `

Эта команда добавит ключ в систему, после перезагрузки, нужно будет только активировать систему

` символы "[" и "]" писать необязательно

*ps: вопрос можно закрывать*

Answer (score 0):

Берешь одну машину, если они все идентичны то вообще отлично.
Ставишь все дрова и программы, ну и саму систему.
Потом берешь Acronis TrueImage или что-то подобное, делаешь слепок системы.

На остальные машины копируешь этот слепок и с помощью этой же программы за 5-10 минут распаковываешь, и вуаля готовая рабочая машинка за 5-10 минут, со всем необходимым ПО.

Единственное что иногда машинки в домене и их к нему нужно прицепить + статические адреса.
Но это все единичные случаи.

Comment: Да это все понятно, вопрос в другом, как сделать так чтобы каждая машина имела свой лиц. ключ, но у меня уже ключ введен и система активирована.

Comment: Отличный совет для тех, кто не умеет пользоваться утилитами Windows, созданными специально для Windows, как ни странно. Создание wim образа - это не только "тупой" слепок диска, это весьма детальная установка, до которой 3rd Party Software дорасти невозможно. По времени восстановления - 20минут. При этом все "плюшки" включая домен.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте поинтересоваться каким софтом Вы пользовались для создание слепка, сохраняющего лицензию? Есть ноут на лицензионной 7-ке, хочу создать бэкап перед установкой 10-ки.

А для Ваших целей лучше всего подошел бы Acronis True Image, он удаляет данные об активации системы при её разворачивании, после чего можно средствами Windows сменить ключ и активировать систему.

Кстати, при переносе на другое железо для сброса данных о лицензии и драйверов используется родная Виндовая утилита Sysprep.exe.